# How to rebase without trashing current commits?

Tags: git, github, rebase

I'm new to Git and GitHub. I forked from an open source project and cloned the fork. The GitHub fork is known as "origin" and I created an alias to the source of the fork "upstream". I switched to the branch "3.x". Created my own feature branch "MyFeature". Worked on that feature and eventually commited it described as "Initial MyFeature commit" and pushed it with:

```
git push --set-upstream origin MyFeature
```

I created a Pull Request and got code review change requests. I edited some files according to code review requests, commited the changes described as "Changes from code review requests".

Before pushing the changes, I rebased with

```
git pull --rebase upstream 3.x
```

Then I pushed the changes with

```
git push -f
```

What I see on GitHub is

```
-o- Initial MyFeature commit
-o- Changes from code review requests
```

The problem is my changes are being trashed by the re-pushing "Initial MyFeature commit" over the "Changes from code review requests". I lose all my changes.

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Is it a private repo or can you share an URL ?

Comment: It's not a private repo. Which url do you need? The main URL is [MuseScore](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore). The PR is [PR6868](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/pull/6868)

Comment: From what I see your changes are not trashed. In the PR view, github lists the commits that are not part of the PR's branch (two individual commits in your case). Do you have some indication that the changes in your first commit are discarded ? or is it just that, inspecting the changes brought by your second commit, you thought your first commit was discarded ?

Comment: When I look at the diff from the first commit, I see the change is there. But when I open the file in my origin at GitHub, I can see that the change isn't there. I had the same thing happen several times in another PR where all my changes from 8 commits were discarded this way.

Comment: In your clone : your changes are present on the `easeInOutPortamento` branch ( [link](https://github.com/ypoissant/MuseScore/tree/easeInOutPortamento), branch used as "source branch" in PR #6868 ). Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I figured it. I was not looking in the right branch. Thank you again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP overlooked a simple setting in the tool he uses (the branch selector in GitHub), which makes this question less likely to help future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pushed your changes to a dedicated branch, which you named `easeInOutPortamento`.

If you inspect your repo through github's website : the branch selected by default is `master` (or `main` since github changed the default branch name of new repos).

If you want to inspect the state of files for another branch, you have to explicitly select it in the "branch/tag" dropdown.